# Rails No Method Error - odd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have a little method to check for words starting with a capital letter defined in an initializer:

```
class String
    def not_proper?
       self[/^[A-Z].*/] != self
    end
end
```

And when I call it in the rails console, everything works as it should.

```
"Africa".not_proper?
>> false
"africa".not_proper?
>> true
```

But when I call it from my controller, as in:

```
success += 1 unless word.not_proper?
```

it throws a "undefined method `not_proper?' for "Africa":String"

What gives?

UPDATE!!!

It now works, as if by magic. I didn't change anything at all from the problem posed above. I can only assume that the "powder unlink" followed by "powder link" hack takes some time to re-initialize? Anyway, thanks as ever everyone for your comments. Have given +1 to your comments by way of thanks.

Comment: Did you reload your server after placing that into an initializer?

Comment: Think so: Am using powder, so did "powder unlink" and then "powder link". This worked previously when I changed the initializer, but perhaps I need some kind of different reload?

Comment: Don't know - I'm not familiar with powder.

Comment: Read section 2.5 of the manual, it refers how to restart it:  http://pow.cx/manual.html

Comment: @Jonathan_W, as stated above, restarting server is definitely a good place to start. Initializer updates won't load until the server is restarted.

Comment: Is your `class String` defined in your initializer or a separate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now works - without my doing anything. It seems that "powder unlink" followed by "powder link" is a poor way to reinitialize the server, as it takes time to take effect. So I will be following @MichaelLynch 's suggestion to restart pow in a better way.